# Unclear behavior maximumSize and sizePolicy

Tags: qt, qlayout

I have simple window with 3 buttons.
Property sizePolicy of the window is Fixed, Fixed.
geometry is 266, 115.
Minimum size is 266, 115.
Maximum size is 16777215, 16777215.

I think in that way: "If sizePolicy is fixed, then i can't stretch window in any size. It must be like in geometry. If sizePolicy is Expanding or Preferred, i can stretch window from minimum to maximum size"

In **real life** only one way i found to disallow stretching window is set maximumSize = minimumSize.

Why the sizePolicy works in unclear way? Does it work?
What i'm doing wrong?

> My english not very good, so be tolerant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [QSizePolicy documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html), you find that:

> The QSizePolicy class is a layout attribute describing horizontal and vertical resizing policy.

So basically, this attribute describing widget behavior only inside QLayout. It doesn't propagate to system window.

If you want to create fixed sized window - just use [setFixedSize()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize).